# PHP for loop takes a long time

Tags: php

Please forgive me, I am just learning PHP and loops. This for loop takes an extremely long time to process and I am not sure why. I am to list all years you have been alive when you enter your age on a form and that age = $age.

```
        //list the years you have been alive
        echo "<br>You know what? Just for fun I am going to list all"
        . " the year's you have been alive. Here you go:<br>";
        $year1 = date("Y");
        for ($y = $age + 1; $y < 100; $y--) {
            if ($y > 0) {
                $yearval = $year1 - $y;
                echo "$yearval<br>";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `for` loop will count backwards indefinitely. To prevent this, you should check that `y` is greater than `0` in addition to checking that it's less than 100:

```
for ($y = $age + 1; $y < 100 && $y > 0; $y--)
```

As:

```
<?php

//list the years you have been alive
echo "<br>You know what? Just for fun I am going to list all the years you have been alive. Here you go:<br>";
$year1 = date("Y");
$age = 20; // Sample data
for ($y = $age + 1; $y < 100 && $y > 0; $y--) {
    $yearval = $year1 - $y;
    echo "$yearval<br>";
}
```

Note that in doing this you no longer need the `if` conditional.

In addition to this, you don't need an apostrophe in `years`.

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/oMiSu)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: *In addition to this, you don't need an apostrophe in `years`.* LOL'd  on that one.  (oh, dear me, I just did it myself)

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop. If `$y < 100` when the loop starts, this condition will always be true because you're subtracting `1` from `$y` each time through the loop. When `$y` reaches `0` it will keep looping with negative values, but it won't print anything those times.

You should be testing whether `$y > 0`:

```
for ($y = $age + 1; $y > 0; $y--) {
    $yearval = $year1 - $y;
    echo "$yearval<br>";
}
```